# Error: "The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level"

Tags: android, kotlin

Relevant portion of my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-Q'
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mykotlintutorials"
        minSdkVersion 'Q'
        targetSdkVersion 'Q'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `minSdkVersion` set to `Q` means that the device you're installing your app on has to have at least that version of Android, or higher. I guess your device is not running Android Q. There are 2 ways to get around this:

1. Reduce the `minSdkVersion` to be the same (or lower) as the device you're installing on
2. [Create an emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) with Android Q, and test on that emulator

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, and I solved it by doing the following:

1. Change the minSdkVersion to the one you are using (mine is 30)
2. Sync the project and rerun it.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me when in build.gradle I changed:

```
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
```

to

```
minSdkVersion = 30
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
```

I solved it by changing it back